# How to convert a String into a String[][]

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a string like this:

```
String string ='{{"INPUT FILE", "NUMBER OF RECORDS"},{"Item File", "11,559"},{"Vendor File", "300"}, {"Purchase History File", "10,000"},{"Total # of requisitions", "10,200,038"}}';
```

And I want to convert it into an array like this:

```
String [][] data = {
          {"INPUT FILE", "NUMBER OF RECORDS"},
          {"Item File", "11,559"},
          {"Vendor File", "300"},
          {"Purchase History File", "10,000"},
          {"Total # of requisitions", "10,200,038"}
      };
```

How could I do that?

Comment: That's not a valid string because it's enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: As in a quick one-liner method? the Java Programming language isn't big on those. You'd have to do some work. Furthermore, strings aren't valid in '' in Java. Now, if you're thinking of Javascript, you're asking a different question.

Comment: no. it's not java. actually, it is a string from SAS. but Java programs needs [][], so I have to convert it.  thanks!

Comment: Furthermore, if you're working in Java, are you sure you want a 2D string and not a HashMap? Or to write a class that encapsulates what obviously seem to be fields, and then have another method that parses your data and uses instances of those classes?

Comment: If it's not Java, how would you ever convert it using Java? :)

Comment: thank you for the detailed comment!  I'm actually learning Power Point program from Apache POI   it is doing some thing like  for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { TableCell cell = table.getCell(i, j); ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String[] first = string.replaceAll("[({{\")(\"}})]","").split("\"},{\"");
String[][] result = new String[first.length][];
for (int i=0; i<first.length; i++)
  result[i] = first[i].split("\", \"");
```

I think that's about right - there may be some fiddly bits with escaped characters.

Fixed some problems with splits on the commas in the numbers.

Note, this is *super* fragile and totally dependent on the format you provided.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to parse it with a 2D array in mind.

Start with the rows (delimited by "},"), then break those into values.

Answer (score 0):

write a method and use StringUtils http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html use one of the split* methods in StringUtils.  You will need to run the split* method twice since you have a two dimensional array.